# problem in execution of sql query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I want to execute this query  but not able to use max() in where condition , please help me in executing this query:

```
SELECT AVG(pushing_force) 
from drawing 
where pushing_force > max(drawing_force) 
group by coil_id 
order by coil_id
```

> ```
> ERROR: ERROR: Aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE<br>
> LINE 1: ...pushing_force) from drawing where pushing_force > max(drawin...
>                                                              ^
> ```

I want to calculate the avg of pushing_force above the max drawing_force for every coil. It should not calculate from 0. example if in a coil pushing_force  = 80 and drrawing_force =60 the it should calculate the avg pushing force from 60 till 80

Comment: you have to use a subquery to find MAX first.

Comment: Have you tried to use `HAVING MAX(...)`? See: [Having](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-having/) Note that The `HAVING` clause specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate returned by the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: drawing_force references the same row. You want a subselect instead.

Comment: yes :SELECT AVG(pushing_force) from drawing group by coil_id having (max(drawing_force)< max(pushing_force)) but it shows, then it is calculating the avg value from 0 to the limit as it satisfying the condition . but need to see the avg above the max drawing force

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT AVG(pushing_force) 
  FROM drawing d1 
 WHERE pushing_force > (
       SELECT max(drawing_force)
         FROM drawing d2 
        WHERE d1.coil_id = d2.coil_id
        )
GROUP BY coil_id
ORDER BY coil_id
```

A similar approach, but maybe faster, looks like

```
SELECT AVG(d1.pushing_force) 
  FROM drawing d1, (
       SELECT coil_id, max(drawing_force) as mdrawing_force
         FROM drawing
        GROUP BY coil_id
       ) d2 
 WHERE d1.pushing_force > d2.mdrawing_force
   AND d1.coil_id = d2.coil_id
GROUP BY d1.coil_id
ORDER BY d1.coil_id
```

Comment: i think my system got hang after executing this query , its still waiting to complete the query.

Comment: if your drawing table is very large and/or the chosen execution plan isn't optimal, the repeatedly executed subquery might cost a lot of performance. Do you have any indexes defined?

Comment: sorry but I have no index defined, the drawing table  is very long, it contains approx 3 million data . its still waiting to complete the query. I have total 6 coil but each coil contain a lot of data in it with time

Comment: A720002 rows are there. can we define the index that it should calculate up to 10000 rows

Comment: OK, 3M rows that's quite a bit. Does the 2nd query show the same miserable performance? An index on `coil_id, drawing_force` might improve performance significantly (but if not, drop it again)

Comment: @that showing correct result , thankyou so much for the approch

Answer (score 0):

Nitesh wrote:

> but need to see the avg above the max drawing force

If you need the average of `pushing_force` above the `max(drawing_force)`, try to use subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(pushing_force) result
FROM 
(
    SELECT pushing_force, max(drawing_force) OVER()  max_drawing_force
    FROM drawing
) t
WHERE t.pushing_force > t.max_drawing_force
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xA6kfKN3Brpt1zjASLGtka/0)